# How to store elements in array?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, momentjs

```
  var currentTimestamp = moment();
   $scope.getAllCandel = [];
   var tradeStartTime = moment().set('hour', 9).set('minutes', 15);

   var diff = currentTimestamp.diff(tradeStartTime,'minutes');

   for(var i =0;i<diff;i++){
      tradeStartTime.add(1, 'minutes');
      // console.log(tradeStartTime);
        $scope.getAllCandel.push(tradeStartTime);
     }
      console.log(JSON.stringify($scope.getAllCandel));
```

I want to print time with interval of 1 min so. Storing int into  in an array but here after loop only single elemnt is getting stored

Comment: What is diff in your for loop? It might be executing only once.

Comment: diff is currenttime - startTime

Comment: What exactly is the question here?

Comment: yes its coming in console how to store it in array

Comment: It is getting stored in your array

Comment: its storing.. inside for loop .but while accessing outside for loop its showing only last element

Comment: add one label to html file and bind this value to label like: get data inside loop var data=JSON.stringify($scope.getAllCandel) and add label in html <label>{{data}}</label>

Comment: add `debugger` an look step by step. `diff`  could be 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can print your time values by using ng-repeat in your HTML.

```
   <div ng-repeat="candel in getAllCandel">
        <p>{{candel }}</p>
   </div>
```

You can pass your array to a function like

```
DummyFunction($scope.getAllCandel);

function DummyFunction(array){
   for(var i=0;i<array.length;i++){
   //Do Computations
}
}
```

You can also store your array the following way.

```
   for(var i =0;i<diff;i++){
      tradeStartTime.add(1, 'minutes');
      // console.log(tradeStartTime);
        $scope.getAllCandel[i]=tradeStartTime;
     }
```

Comment: actually am doing diffrent stuff with this .want to pass this array to the other function

Comment: What happened when you put console.log($scope.getAllCandel) inside the for loop. Was it printing one value array only once? or many array with increasing order of elements?

Comment: any other solution

Comment: I have updated the solution but this doesn't change anything. Its just another way of storing array.

Comment: dont want to bring that in html ..Actually i have an api n from ther m picking time and printing it on screen.if suppose time:10:00 is missing am adding it manually and printing it.. so above part is for to create dummy array of time and matching them to original data.if data not found m pushing that particular data to original

Comment: Ok so what seems to be the probelm?

Comment: $scope.getAllCandel[i]=tradeStartTime ... worked thank u

Answer (score 1):

Try `var module = angular.module('myApp', []);

```
            module.controller('TimeCtrl', function($scope, $interval) {
                var tick = function() {
                    $scope.clock = Date.now();
                }
                tick();
                $interval(tick, 10000);
            });
            <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.11/angular.min.js"></script>

            <div ng-app="myApp">
              <div ng-controller='TimeCtrl'>
                <p>{{ clock | date:'MM/dd/yyyy @ h:mma'}}</p>
```

`